# Virtual Box не запускает Android 5.1 и 6.0

Tags: virtualbox

Virtual Box не запускает Android 5.1 и 6.0.
Но с версией 4.4.4 все хорошо.

Выдает такую ошибку:

**Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины Google Nexus 4 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280.
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: ConsoleWrap
Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}**

Comment: у вас часом не стоит HyperV?

Comment: Где это посмотреть?

Comment: подобные вопросы всегда повергают меня в шок http://imgur.com/Fs1dJ1S http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UxSlUEZSwk0/TwTPlNEfqYI/AAAAAAAAAfc/yXWjunfZmEM/s1600/NewVM01.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нету аппаратной виртуализации (VT-x) или она просто не включена. 
Скорее всего не включена.

В включать ее нужно в биосе

Comment: Нет, я ее включил. Проблема не в этом.

Comment: Ошибка говорит об обратном.Попробуйте выключить VT-x для android 5.1 и 6.

Comment: Где конкретно мне включить VT?

Comment: В конфиге вашамашина.vbox найти <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true"/> и заменить на <HardwareVirtEx enabled="false"/>. Я так понимаю у вас версия 4.13>= попробуйте откатится на 4.12 версию. она не такая глючная